# SQL Join query to return sum and most recent entries

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, join, eloquent

Im trying to put together an SQL query in a Laravel app to create a report on  **customers**, **agents**, and **orders** and need some assistance.

Ive have illustrated my db tables and excluded unnecessary fields from the schema below:

**CUSTOMERS TABLE**

```
---------------------------------------------
cust_id     cust_name           
---------------------------------------------
1           Joe 
2           Allan
3           Rick
4           Bill
```

**AGENTS TABLE**

Each agent is related to the customer via a cust_id foreign key:

```
---------------------------------------------
agent_id    agent_name  cust_id 
---------------------------------------------
1           Mike        2
2           Arnold      4
3           Lucy        1
4           Tom         3
```

**ORDERS TABLE**

The orders table contains all orders made by customers (referenced by cust_id via foreign key), including order date and amount:

```
-----------------------------------------------
ord_id      cust_id     date        amount  
-----------------------------------------------
1           1           1/1/2001    50.00
2           1           1/1/2001    20.00
3           2           2/1/2001    20.00
4           4           2/1/2001    30.00
5           3           2/1/2001    75.00
6           3           3/1/2001    35.00
7           1           4/1/2001    20.00
8           3           5/1/2001    75.00
9           2           5/1/2001    10.00
```

**DESIRED QUERY RESULTS:**

I would like to build a query to retrieve the agent name, most recent sale date, most recent sale amount and total amount of sales for each customer (sorted by customer name):

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
custName    agentName   LastSaleDate    LastSaleAmt     TotalSales  
------------------------------------------------------------------
Allan       Mike        10.00           5/1/2001        30.00
Bill        Arnold      30.00           2/1/2001        30.00           
Joe         Lucy        20.00           4/1/2001        90.00
Rick        Tom         75.00           5/1/2001        185.00
```

**Current Situation:**

Thus far, I have created all the laravel models and setup eloquent relationships, but suspect that the query above should be done using regular SQL instead of ORM.

Using SQL, I  can retrieve the customer name, agent name and total sales, but not the last sale date and last sale amount:

```
SELECT customers.name, agents.name, SUM(orders.amount) FROM customers
LEFT JOIN agents
ON customers.id=agents.cust_id
LEFT JOIN orders
ON customers.id=orders.cust_id
GROUP BY customers.id, agents.name
ORDER BY customers.name ASC
```

How can this query be extended to include the most recent sale date and amounts?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: So each agent has exactly one customer?

Comment: @Strawberry Yes, That is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to aggregate to get the total and the last sale date.  Then join back in the `orders` information to get the last amount:

```
select oca.name, oca.agentname, oca.sales, oca.lastSaleDate,
       o.amount as lastSaleAmount
from (select c.id, c.name, a.name as agentname, sum(o.amount) as sales,
             max(o.date) as lastSaleDate
      from orders o join
           customers c
           on o.cust_id = c.id join
           agents a
           on c.id = a.cust_id
      group by c.id, c.name, a.name
     ) oca join
     orders o
     on o.cust_id = oca.cust_id and oca.lastSaleDate = o.date
```

Comment: Many thanks Gordon - im going to give this a try and report back / mark as complete.

Comment: Works perfectly - I just need to get a better understanding of this. Thank you for taking time to answer.